# elasticsearch service wrapper on gentoo

Tags: java, gentoo, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch installed and working in /opt/elasticsearch. I want to install a service wrapper for it to start/stop/restart it as a service. Elasticsearch recommends using java-service-wrapper:

```
curl -L http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper/tarball/master | tar -xz
mv *servicewrapper*/service elasticsearch/bin/

# Setup ElasticSearch as a service:
elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch install
```

However, the start of a service fails with the following message: `the value of wrapper.java.command does not appear to be a java binary`. I don't really know where to start debugging and would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration problem. `wrapper.java.command` should point to a valid java binary.

Comment: if you are on gentoo -only the true path, not script nor symbolic link to java binary